# Can we represent a $N-1$ rectifiable set locally as a graph, with some price?

Tags: geometric-measure-theory

This is a follow up discussion for [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223136/the-partition-of-n-1-rectifiable-set) post.

Let me copy part of the definition here.

Let $S\subset \mathbb R^N$ be a $N-1$ rectifiable set with $\mathcal H^{N-1}(S)<\infty$.

***My (updated) question:***

Can we find, for any $\epsilon>0$ be given, a set $S_0\subset S$ with $\mathcal H^{N-1}(S\setminus S_0)<\epsilon$ so that for each $x_0\in S_0$, we can choose a ball (cube) $B$ centered at $x_0$ with radius $r>0$ so that:

I can choose a direction vector $\nu$ so that each slice $B_x$, for $x\in B_\nu$, only intersect with $S\cap B$ once?

Here by slice $B_x$ please refer to the following definition:

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\pi_\nu = \{x\in\mathbb R^N:\,<x,\nu>=0\};\\
B_x=\{t\in R:\, x+t\nu\in B\}\,\,(x\in\pi_\nu);\\
B_\nu = \{x\in\pi_\nu:\,B_x\neq \varnothing\}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

By @Anton Petrunin's answer in the linked post, this question is equivalent to asking can we represent this curve locally as a graph.

Little background: Here my set $S$ is the jump set of a $BV$ function in $\mathbb R^N$.

***My try:***
We know that $\mathcal H^{N-1}$ a.e. $x\in S$ has density $1$. (I don't know whether this is hold for general rectifiable curve but it does hold in my case). That is, for a.e. $x\in S$ we have 
$$
\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\mathcal H^{N-1}(S\cap S(x,r))}{S_{N}r^{N-1}} = 1
$$
where $S_N$ denote the measure of unit sphere in $\mathbb R^{N}$.

Therefore, we have, for $r$ small enough, 
$$
\mathcal H^{N-1}(S\cap S(x,r))\geq {S_{N}r^{N-1}}(1-\epsilon)
$$

My idea is that as $r$ getting smaller, density $1$ makes sure that $S\cap B(x,r)$ can not bending too much other wise the limit is not $1$. But I can't not finish my argument from here... Please advise!

Comment: Btw, being rectifiable is the same as having density $1$ a.e., by a theorem of Preiss.

Comment: I think the case logarithmic spiral can be handled by kill the small pieces which is around the center.